# Is Excel Javascript API only for creating Add-Ins?

Tags: javascript, excel, api, office-js

I am thinking about using the API for quickly exchanging lots of excel data with a webserver. Especially for administration purposes.

**Requirements**

1. Create a connection with a custom webserver instead of localhost [ON OPEN]
2. Refresh/load the data from the website into the excel workbook when the excel file is opened [ON OPEN]
3. Send a lock command to the webserver to prevent other users from making changes at the same time as well [ON OPEN]
4. Return all the data to the webserver [ON SAVE]
5. Display error message when the format is incorrect [ON SAVE]
   Remove the lock [ON CLOSE]

**A few questions**

1. Does the API only  works with localhost or with a custom webserver
   as well?
2. Is there a way to create an event for ON OPEN?
3. Is there a way to create an event for ON SAVE?
4. Is there a way to create an event for ON CLOSE?

Answer (score 0):

The Office.js APIs work with any web server. Localhost is only used when developing/testing.

Any code that you want to run when the add-in opens can be put in the call of `Office.onReady` (or `Office.initialize`).

There is currently no way to handle the Save or Close events.